# Java Better way to add spaces

Tags: java

For Example, is there a better way to do this?

```
public static String Name = "Name";
public static double Version = 0.1;

public Main() {
    Display.setTitle(Name + " " + Version);
}
```

I don't like doing

```
    + " " +
```

Comment: Check String.format

Comment: Why don't you like it? What do you mean by "better"? It's 5 characters and not particularly slow - you're not going to improve on that one way or the other.

Comment: Anything using `String.format("%s %s",name,version)` is going to invoke some pretty heavy machinery behind the scenes... what you have is short, simple and fast.

Comment: Yes, what exactly don't you like about it?  Would you prefer a constant like `+ SPACE + `?

Comment: Different languages have different shortcuts for String concatenation. That's Java's version. Some SQL dialects use `|| ' ' ||`, PHP uses `. " " .`. You can notice a pattern there.

Comment: You can think of adding keyboard shortcut to that combination of characters. If the shortcut combination of keys has been pressed, then it could let this characters combination appear. It doesn't change the way Java reads the combination, as it seems to be quick, but it might help you save a bit of time.

Comment: You can also do `Name + ' ' + Version` (avoiding the unnecessary creation of a String of one character).

Answer (score 2):

Modern releases of Java come with a `printf` like utility which permits you to declare the formatting string, replacing formatting fields with values.

```
String s = String.format("%s %f", Name, Version);
```

At first glance, this sounds like it will be a heavy solution, but when you consider all of the heap thrashing you do with the "many Strings built and discarded to get your answer", it often is more efficient.

A second approach is to simply build up your string with a `StringBuilder`.

```
SringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append(Name);
buffer.append(" ");
buffer.append(Double.toString(Version));
String s = buffer.toString();
```

And while it seems worse than some solutions, it is likely more efficient than the `Name + " " + Version` solution, in the cases where the compiler cannot determine what you are attempting.  (If it can determine what you are attempting, then the `Name + " " + Version` approach will silently be rewritten at compile time to use `StringBuilder` anyway).

Comment: Could you change comma to dot between words String and format?

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal Of course!  Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Now I see that I could have edited your answer with the use of Stack Exchange Android app. Stack Overflow app shows that I don't have permission to edit this post (I would of course do it without your intervention need, as it would take less time to edit it instead of writing a comment to you, but I thought my reputation was too small yet). Sometimes I don't really understand Stack Overflow Android app ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal I don't use the Android App, but I'm never opposed to fixing what I write, and am pleased to hear people offering suggestions to make my answers better.  Thank you very much for noticing my typo, and I am very happy to have changed it!

Comment: @Edwin `buffer.append(Version)` is likely more efficient. At the very least, it will be no less efficient, and is more concise.

Comment: @Edwin "[String.format] often is more efficient." I find this quite hard to believe. `String.format` has to tokenize the format string, and involves the current locale etc, and then it concatenates the string; using `+` or `StringBuilder` just concatenates the string, i.e. it skips those initial stages. It's hard to see how doing that extra work could still be faster. Can you back up your claim with numbers?

Comment: @AndyTurner Stack frames in Java are not free, and neither is heap allocation.  It all boils down to which one manages to do it faster, which is better proven with bench marking than with argument.  `printf` has had over 30 years of optimization, and typically fills out strings in a 2-pass approach (one to carve out the string constants and fields, a second to fill them).  That can all be done in one method call, with minimal heap creation.  Is one faster than the other?  I don't know, but I do know that I've seen reversals in what I "knew" was performant, over time.

Comment: @EdwinBuck and I was asking you for your benchmarking to back up the claim :) A cursory google search turned up [this](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/java-string-concatenation-vs-stringbuilder-vs-string-format-performance), which suggests roughly an order of magnitude difference between `String.format` and `+`, in favour of `+` (simply from a speed perspective). (Standard disclaimers about how hard microbenchmarks are to write etc).

Comment: @AndyTurner It's nearly 3 AM over here.  I wouldn't hold your breath for my bench marking code.  :)  You've provided some evidence that supports your position.  I'm happy to believe it.  The bench mark however, is far from perfect.  Seems like they didn't do a warm up till times stabilized (which means that the `+` operator is likely a little faster than they reported.  I can't tell what version / build they did it against, a lot could have changed in the last 2 years.  In my attempt to repo, concatenation with `+` was faster than the builder call!  But printf was still the slowest :)

Answer (score 1):

If you could make `Name` and `Version` `final` (I mean, they do *look* like constants), it would be better, because

```
Name + " " + Version
```

would then be a compile-time constant expression, so it would be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to join two things into one string, I'd agree with the comments saying that `+ " " +` is the way to go. If you have more than two separate strings and want to keep it readable, `String.join()` is an alternative to `String.format()` that does not require the formatting syntax. It does however require all the parts being strings, so having a double makes it more complicated.

```
// if Version was a string
String.join(" ", name, version, more, strings)

// as Version is double, you have to convert it first
String.join(" ", name, version + "", more, strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way with `printf`

For example:

```
System.out.printf("%5s%1f", name, version);
```

This will print 5 spaces then name, 1 space then version.
You can also do:

```
System.out.printf("%-5s%f", name, version);
```

This will print 5 spaces after the string. etc.

source: [sourcelink](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/SystemoutprintfStringis5snA.htm)